# É possível saber que um option foi selecionado em evento javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu sei que é possível pegar o valor de um `select` selecionado com:

```
$("id option:selected").val()
```

Porém queria saber se é possível pegar quando algum desse `select` é selecionado via evento, como por exemplo, ao selecionar um `option`, disparar alguma função.

Acredito que ficaria algo do tipo:

```
$("#ProcessoId").on('select', function () {
    alert("ooi");

});
```

Ou:

```
$("#ProcessoId").on('selected', function () {
    alert("ooi");

});
```

Mas até então não consegui fazer funcionar.

Comment: Não ficou claro o que você deseja fazer. Você gostaria de definir uma função diferente para cada valor do `select` e, ao selecionar, executar a função correspondente ao valor selecionado?

Comment: Eu pretendo ao usuário selecionar um select de um option, disparar alguma coisa, não precisa ser diferente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você está procurando é o evento [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) do jQuery:

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  var valor = $(this).val();   // aqui vc pega cada valor selecionado com o this
  alert("evento disparado e o valor é: " + valor);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option value="um">Um</option>
  <option value="dois">Dois</option>
  <option value="tres">Três</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sim eu pensei no change, pensei que não daria certo mas já tive uma ideia aqui que vai fazer ele da certo

Answer (score 1):

Segue exemplo onde você pode definir diferentes ações para cada `option` do `select` selecionado pelo usuário.

```js
$('#marca').change(function() {
  var marca = $('#marca').val();
  switch (marca) {
    case '':
      alert ("Selecione uma marca!")
      break;
    case 'VW':
      alert ("Selecionou Volkswagen")
      break;
    case 'GM':
      alert ("Selecionou Chevrolet")
      break;
    case 'FIAT':
      alert ("Selecionou FIAT")
      break;
    default:
      alert ("Selecione uma marca!")
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name='marca' id='marca' required>
  <option value=''>Selecione a marca</option>
  <option value='VW'>Volkswagen</option>
  <option value='GM'>Chevrolet</option>
  <option value='FIAT'>FIAT</option>
</select>
```